# Jupyter lab is freezing up when moving from file to file(united.ipynb). How can I stop this from happening?

Tags: ssl-certificate, jupyter-lab

I am new to Jupyter labs so please excuse my unknowing. I have tried to up date my SSL with pip install certifi. I have tried to stop X-frozen_modues with pluging straight in to the terminal(X_forzen_moduals=off), with each change in terminal, I have restarted the terminal in the virtual emviromment. I have been using Jupyter labs for about a year and just recently has this issue come up.
I use python 3.11 and my version of Jupyter lab is 3.6.2 and im on a Macbook pro Sonama. Jupyter lab starts for me won’t let me type but a min and if I touch another folder it shuts down. Very slow when it does work.

Here is what my terminal says:
➜ data-analysis source .venv/bin/activate
(.venv) ➜ data-analysis jupyter lab
[I 2023-12-04 05:50:50.660 ServerApp] Package jupyterlab took 0.0000s to import
[I 2023-12-04 05:50:50.665 ServerApp] Package jupyter_server_fileid took 0.0045s to import
[I 2023-12-04 05:50:50.675 ServerApp] Package jupyter_server_terminals took 0.0097s to import
[I 2023-12-04 05:50:50.724 ServerApp] Package jupyter_server_ydoc took 0.0484s to import
[I 2023-12-04 05:50:50.724 ServerApp] Package nbclassic took 0.0000s to import
[W 2023-12-04 05:50:50.727 ServerApp] A _jupyter_server_extension_points function was not found in nbclassic. Instead, a _jupyter_server_extension_paths function was found and will be used for now. This function name will be deprecated in future releases of Jupyter Server.
[I 2023-12-04 05:50:50.727 ServerApp] Package notebook_shim took 0.0000s to import
[W 2023-12-04 05:50:50.727 ServerApp] A _jupyter_server_extension_points function was not found in notebook_shim. Instead, a _jupyter_server_extension_paths function was found and will be used for now. This function name will be deprecated in future releases of Jupyter Server.
[I 2023-12-04 05:50:50.732 ServerApp] jupyter_server_fileid | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2023-12-04 05:50:50.735 ServerApp] jupyter_server_terminals | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2023-12-04 05:50:50.739 ServerApp] jupyter_server_ydoc | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2023-12-04 05:50:50.743 ServerApp] jupyterlab | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2023-12-04 05:50:50.747 ServerApp] nbclassic | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2023-12-04 05:50:51.101 ServerApp] notebook_shim | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2023-12-04 05:50:51.428 ServerApp] notebook_shim | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2023-12-04 05:50:51.428 FileIdExtension] Configured File ID manager: ArbitraryFileIdManager
[I 2023-12-04 05:50:51.428 FileIdExtension]
[I 2023-12-04 05:50:51.429 FileIdExtension]
[I 2023-12-04 05:50:51.431 FileIdExtension] ArbitraryFileIdManager : Successfully connected to database file.
[I 2023-12-04 05:50:51.432 FileIdExtension] ArbitraryFileIdManager : Creating File ID tables and indices with journal_mode = DELETE
[I 2023-12-04 05:50:51.435 FileIdExtension] Attached event listeners.
[I 2023-12-04 05:50:51.435 ServerApp] jupyter_server_fileid | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2023-12-04 05:50:51.437 ServerApp] jupyter_server_terminals | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2023-12-04 05:50:51.437 ServerApp] jupyter_server_ydoc | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2023-12-04 05:50:51.438 LabApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from analysis/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jupyterlab
[I 2023-12-04 05:50:51.438 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is /Users//Desktop/Python/data-analysis/.venv/share/jupyter/lab
[I 2023-12-04 05:50:51.441 ServerApp] jupyterlab | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2023-12-04 05:50:51.448 ServerApp] nbclassic | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2023-12-04 05:50:51.449 ServerApp] Serving notebooks from local directory:

0.00s - Debugger warning: It seems that frozen modules are being used, which may
0.00s - make the debugger miss breakpoints. Please pass -Xfrozen_modules=off
0.00s - to python to disable frozen modules.
0.00s - Note: Debugging will proceed. Set PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION=1 to disable this validation.
[I 2023-12-04 05:50:55.257 LabApp] Build is up to date
[W 2023-12-04 05:50:56.558 ServerApp] SSL Error on 22 (‘2606:50c0:8000::153’, 443, 0, 0): [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:992)
[I

I have tried to up date my SSL with pip install certifi. I have tried to stop X-frozen_modues with pluging straight in to the terminal(X_forzen_moduals=off), with each change in terminal, I have restarted the terminal in the virtual emviromment.

Comment: The performance of your browser is unrelated to the SSL certificate warning. What browser do you use? Could you try (a) changing hidden mode in settings (https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/4292#issuecomment-1508184584), (b) upgrading to JupyterLab 4.0, (c) changing the Notebook windowing mode to full in settings?

Comment: I have a Mac and use the default Safari. Should I use Crome or? I have not had a problem until just recently. I have upgraded JupyterLab 4.0 still having the same issue. Also, installed Docker hopefully homebrew will help resolve the issues. I just ran Jupyter lab and it works.@krassowski